# jQuery upload plugin to work with JSP/Java

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

Upload a file to the application by submitting a form (enctype: multipart/form-data) to a JSP action which handles the rest (including writing the file to the disk, processing and returning some xml data about the upload).

Until recently, I was using this plugin:
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

This does not work well for two reasons:

- it breaks on Internet Explorer
- the code is written in half jquery, half native javascript and not in your usual plugin authoring form, which makes it harder to debug.

I've also looked at Uploadify ( http://www.uploadify.com/ ) but it takes a radically different approach which would require a lot of back-end changes.

Do you know any similar submit-form-in-hidden-iframe plugins that are cleaner / cross-browser compatible? Or alternative solutions that I'm missing?

Please note that I can't use a regular  because of the specific requirements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Pretty nice & simple

Answer (score 0):

It's not jQuery but this is quite nice.

http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/

Also YUI has an uploader.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with this one:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

Allthough this is not a JQuery plugin, I can recommand [SwfUpload](http://swfupload.org/) for this kind of functionality. It's a combination of Flash and javascript which allowed me to do exactly what I wanted to without having to worry about the "upload"-part.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jqUploader](http://www.pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/) : it's written in pure jquery plugin style and uses a flash file to display a progress bar. Very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You may try: [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php). It's back-end independent, and cross-browser.