# Java file upload

Tags: java, html

can i upload a file(image) without submitting the form..

Basically i want to create a webpage where a user can upload an image and preview it side by side but this should not submit my form.

**i dont wanna use jquery**

Comment: Why is this tagged java?

Comment: bcoz m using java and jsp to do this ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this is](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery/) what you want But it uses PHP for sever side you can use what ever you want!

[image: Ajax Upload !]

All you have to do is create a page which will handle the ajax call, which is saving the image and returning string "true" in case of succeeds. and for Java [this (Handling Form-based File Upload with Java Servlet or JSP)](http://www.developershome.com/wap/wapUpload/wap_upload.asp?page=jsp) should help you.

Check this one out [ioncannon.net](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/38/ajax-file-upload-progress-for-java-using-commons-fileupload-and-prototype/)

Comment: the demo on side is not working but i have download it and its working fine and shine.

Comment: i dont know anything about PHP, do we need any server for that and how to setup it to test, i want server side language to be java...

Comment: @omeid :i knw how to upload.. but the thing is i dont want one extra page(jsp) to be processed.. and it should be dynamic the way it is in gmail... when we attach an attachment it starts uploading it.. i want something of that sort..

Comment: You extra page will not be visible to user and will work on background  with AJAX. you will have some JavaScript with JQuery on your page and it will send file to the page on server and will show response based on your code.

Comment: the demo is not working error 404 ...
can any1 please share a complete example please ?? or have any idea how gmail is working have to implement almost the same stuff

Comment: you came late, :D this one is now working http://www.awrang.com/aaaajax-file-upload/ :)

Comment: @Omeid - where can i get the code for this ??? i am new to AJAX and jquery... and can it be done using java as well as this is in PHP?

Comment: Get the code from here http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery/ and yes it can be done with java as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can have two forms on the page. One to upload the image and other one for something else. Just don't nest them.

Comment: good idea will try implementing this... will get back soon :)

Comment: But this idea will refresh the page unless you use iframe

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to implement this with AJAX but, if it's even possible, it would be a nasty hack. About the best you can do reasonably is to put the file upload form in an iframe, and after posting the file with AJAX, redraw the page with the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) .Also [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171953/jquery-upload-plugin-to-work-with-jsp-java)